# subtracting list isn't working. I subtracting of every other element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, subtraction

I'm new (few days) to Python, so forgive me.  I'm trying to subtract one list from another put that into a list and sum that list.

```
with open(pybankfile, newline="") as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

    # @NOTE: This time, we do not use `next(csv_reader)` because there is no header for this file

    # Read the header row first (skip this step if there is now header)
    csv_header = next(csvfile)
    lst =[]
    print(f"CSV Header: {csv_header}")
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    data = list(reader)
    maxnum = max(data, key=lambda row: int(row[1]))
    minnum = min(data, key=lambda row: int(row[1]))
    second_column = [int(row[1]) for row in data]
    #third_column = [int(row[2]) - int(row[1]) for row in second_column]
    #dy = sum(third_column)
    countmths = len(second_column) 
    y= (second_column[1::2])
    x= (second_column[::2])
    d=[(b - a)  for a, b in zip(y, x)]

    dy=sum(d)
    print(d)
    print (x)
    print(y)
    print(dy)


    sort_col_2 = sorted(second_column)
    tot = sum(second_column)
    avg_bal = tot / countmths
    avg_diff = dy / 85


    #print values
    print(f"minimum: {minnum}")
    print(f"maximum: {maxnum}")
    print(f"Balance: {tot}")
    print(f"Average:{avg_bal}")
    print(f"Avg Diff:{avg_diff}")
```

The newly created lists print like I'd expect but the subtraction produces weird results -- seems to yield every other difference rather than all differences.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You provided your code, which is good. What's the input? What's the actual output? What should it print?

Comment: input is a csv file of two columns, that reads in fine, and I can seemingly get the values in the second column into another list (second_column). Now I want to determine the average difference between elements in the "second_column", so I figured: slice the "second _column" into two columns one made up of 1 to N step 2 and the other 0:N step 2 so that I could subtract successive values  I found the code with zip but it seems to be giving me every other difference rather than EVERY difference. Sorry. I am so new to this, and I'm under pressure to learn quickly.

Comment: list1[1,2,3]
List2[2,3,4]
List2_-List1[1,1,1]

Comment: This line of code seems to have done the trick:

d= [second_column[i + 1] - second_column[i] for i in range(len(second_column)-1)]

Answer (score 0):

diff_sum= [second_column[i + 1] - second_column[i] for i in range(len(second_column)-1)]

I love nice and simple and efficient. I don't pretend to know it well, but simplicity is the beginning.

Thanks, all.